# Proof of GOSS algorithm in lightGBM paper

Tags: lightgbm, theory

In the LightGBM paper the authors make use of a newly developed sampling method `GOSS` to reduce the number of data instances needed for finding the best split of a given feature in a tree-node.

They give an error estimation for the error made by sampling instead of taking the entire data (Theorem 3.2 in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/lightgbm.pdf)

I am interested in the proof of this Theorem for which the paper refers to "supplementary materials"

Where can I find those?

Answer (score 1):

the proof can be found here:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/hash/6449f44a102fde848669bdd9eb6b76fa-Abstract.html

then hit the button `Supplemental`.